# Intellij IDEA--How to modify build.gradle by Project Structure?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, lwjgl

I need to use a 3rd library. I've tried open **Project Structure** and add libraries to that Module.

[add library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Oui.png)

[modification revert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgV7v.png)

but when I click green"+" button in Gradle Tool Window, all modification disappear!

I cannot figure the reason, is that a BUG?

if not, how can I change gradle setting by Project Structure?

Answer (score 1):

You should not add dependencies by using the Project Structure but instead declare them in your *build.gradle* file.

So you will have something like:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.lwjgl', name: 'lwjgl', version: '3.1.1'
}
```

If you do not have auto import enabled for your gradle project you have to refresh the project in the gradle toolbar.

Here is the relevant part for further reading:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:module_dependencies